# Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install hangs on reboot (i386 Server on Acer Travelmate laptop)

Tags: server, shutdown, 16.04, acer

I've used an old Acer Travelmate 4000 laptop as my local server for ages with Ubuntu Desktop.

This year, I installed 16.04 i386 Server Edition and couldn't be happier. The entire working set of Linux, network stack and apache2 uses only 37MB of the 2GB onboard... No Swap For You!

Trouble is, issuing a reboot (or shutdown) command always hangs at the same point at the console: 'Reached target Shutdown', requiring a hard power off and restart.

What can I can do to diagnose this further?

**UPDATE**: Per suggestion, I keyed commands on the console under sudo to 'systemctl start debug-shell' followed by a 'reboot'.

However, this vanilla server lacks a window manager, so when the final console message 'Reached target Shutdown' appears, no keystroke combination is able to spawn a VT and list any failed jobs. The Alt+SysRq incantation is also ineffective at continuing the reboot.

Anyway, there is now a new last-gasp message line which reads: "[278.430967] systemd-shutdown: Failed to finalize DM devices. ignoring"

I tried the workaround to disable swap space during shutdown in a [similar bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788303), but it didn't help; probably because my 3GB swapfile is unused and /tmp usage is minimal (~2%).

Is there anything else I can try to move the markers forward here?

**UPDATE 2:** Capturing the output of the suggested journalctl and systemctl commands to a file yielded nothing out of the ordinary.

Since there's no GUI on this server, I used [this github code](https://github.com/kos0/addRemoveDistribution.git) to enable Xenial Proposed before updating/upgrading/rebooting to ensure the new systemd-229 was in the mix.

Sadly, it made no difference. I don't know if it's related, but I took the option at Ubuntu installation time to use default LVM Volume Groups for /boot, /home, /var, /tmp and swap.

Am I really the only one seeing this problem?

(Here's a screenshot of the console after issuing a reboot, plus waiting another 3 minutes or so):

[image: screenshot of the console]

Comment: Prior to shutdown open a terminal and type: `systemctl start debug-shell` followed by your root pwd. When the shutdown or reboot hangs press escape to see behind the splash and then ctl+alt+F9 to enter vt9. Once there enter `systemctl list-jobs`, then `systemctl --failed` I am unaware of a way to save this info to a file to upload here but you can take a pic. I am curious if the swap partition failed to stop and timed out. Please post pic or output data by editing your question. Also you can hold alt+Sys rq while typing r,e,i,s,u,b, one letter at a time and the reboot will continue.

Comment: I am aware of the linked bug.  It is supposed to be fixed in Xenial Proposed, so you could try updating.  I am unaware of any further direction you can take.  Note: I did find a way to capture the debug info in vt9.  For every output command run e.g. above add `>>file.text` and the output will append to that "file.text" For instance, `journalctl -b >>debuginfo.text` followed by `systemctl --failed >>debuginfo.text` and the output data from both commands will append to file "debuginfo.text" on `/` for analysis later.  I wish I could help you further.  Good luck.

Comment: If you haven't yet, try using Upstart instead of systemd to initialize the system.  In the grub menu switch to "Advanced options for Ubuntu" then choose the kernel image listed with upstart appended to the end.  Read this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers you can make the upstart the default boot BUT I would test using upstart for a while to be sure it works many times in a row first.  Then file a bug report about the systemd DM failure.

Comment: Ack! That was a non-starter. I had no upstart option in any of my grub menus - I guess with 16.04 it's systemd or bust. Emphasis on bust. Per the instructions in your wiki link, I installed upstart-sysv manually, but it completely hosed the machine. No amount of recovery mode fapping let me uninstall upstart and go back to systemd. Even re-using the LVG on a re-install didn't save the /home, /var, etc. content. In short, I'm going for coffee :(

Comment: To clarify: Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop still offers the boot time option to use upstart. However, this issue is with 16.04 Server Edition, which seems to only support systemd. I'm thinking the root cause is related to the message: systemd-shutdown: Failed to finalize DM devices. ignoring. I'll track issues related to that message and post any results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 as soon as it was available, but it didn't fix this problem. Nor did subsequent package upgrades applied since then.

However, todays package upgrades must've included a fix as I can now happily issue a regular 'sudo reboot' from a remote SSH session and re-connect to the server within a minute or two.

Here's the most recent entry from my /var/log/apt/history.log:

Upgrade: libsystemd0:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), udev:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), libudev1:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), python3-distupgrade:i386 (1:16.10.7, 1:16.10.8), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:i386 (1:16.10.7, 1:16.10.8), systemd-sysv:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), libpam-systemd:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), systemd:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1), libnss-resolve:i386 (231-9git1, 231-9ubuntu1)

From among that list, a huge "Thank You!" goes out to whichever package maintainer applied the magic incantation needed... you know who you are :)

**UPDATE** As Ubuntu no longer supports i386 machines, I've happily switched to Lubuntu 18.04. Tastes great, less filling!

Answer (score 0):

Who knows when/if this problem: "systemd-shutdown: Failed to finalize DM devices. ignoring." will ever be fixed on this old platform - nothing I've read would suggest it'll be anytime soon.

In the meantime, this work-around allows me to reboot my server without physically power cycling the machine.

All the following commands are under sudo:

- Put these commands into a file such as ~/sysrq-reboot.sh
  `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  sync && echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`
- chmod +x the file to make it executable
- then, to reboot just run the script with sudo ~/sysrq-reboot.sh

If running the script remotely via ssh, I find I also need to hard close my ssh window and re-establish a new ssh session (after waiting a minute for the machine to become reachable).